# Many to many json request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, backend

A Contract has several AbsenceType, and an AbsentType can be in several different Contracts. So I made a manyToMany relation in both classes.

```java
Entity
@Table(name = "contract")
@JsonIdentityInfo(  
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id")

@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Contract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "employee")
    private int employee;


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "contracts")
    private List<AbsenceType> absence_types;

    // ... getteur setteur contructor
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "absence_type")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIdentityInfo(  
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id")
public class AbsenceType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // hexa : #FFFFFF
    @Column(name = "color")
    private String color;

    
    @Column(name = "is_paid")
    private boolean is_paid;

    @ManyToMany
    @Column(name = "contracts")
    private List<Contract> contracts;
 // ... getteur setteur contructor
```

I want to be able to create empty Absence types and then when I create a contract, give in my json, the previously created absenceType and not create a new AbsenceType.

In the idea I do this:

```json
{
    "id": 1 # Exemple, in real in don't had id on json
    "name": "Congé sans solde",
    "color": "ff4040",
    "is_paid": false,
    "contracts": []
}
```

and after ->

```json
{
    "name": "Contract4",
    "employee": 3,
    "absence_types" : [
        {
            "id":1
        }
    ]
}
```

But the response when i get all contracts is:

```json
    {
        "id": 621,
        "name": "Contract4",
        "employee": 3,
        "absenceTypes": []
    }
```

But i want :

```json
    {
        "id": 621,
        "name": "Contract4",
        "employee": 3,
        "absenceTypes": [
        {
             "id": 1,
             "name": "Congé sans solde",
             "color": "ff4040",
             "contracts" : [ dudo, i don't think about infinite recursion problem for the moment haha]
        }
    }
```

For all of my DAO i have a generic class, how look like this

```
public void save(T obj) {
        Session session = openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

and on my Contract controller

```
@PostMapping("")
   public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody Contract contract) {
       // Error 422 if the input role variable is null
       if (contract == null)
           new ResponseEntity<String>("Can't create null absenceType", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
       contractDAO.save(contract);
       return new ResponseEntity<>("absenceType saved !", HttpStatus.OK);
   }
```

Comment: Telling us "It doesn't work" is a poor way to get a solution. If your computer stops working do you take it the shop and simply say "It doesn't work"? We need to know what you did that perform as expected, what actually happens instead, and what -- if any -- errors are produced along the way.

Comment: I have edited the post, hoping to make it clearer.

Comment: Check / post your toString method. It is also possible that `AbsenceType` is calling `Contract` and `Contract` is calling `AbsenceType` causing infinite recursion.

Comment: Post the stacktrace / error message.

Comment: I don't have any error message.
Only the wrong output. 
And i don't have to string method on my class.

Comment: First, please verify that the request json contains something in the array. Also, your class definitely inherited a `toString` method.

Comment: How are you generating the json?

Comment: @TheHeadRush Like i said: 
I create my AbsenceType first, for the moment, it should not have any Contract to it.
so i do :

{
   "id": 602,
    "name": "RTT",
    "color": "ff4040",
    "is_paid": false,
    "contracts": [
    ]
}

after that when i create Contract i whan to be able to assign previously created AbsenceType.

so i do :

{
    "name": "Contract4",
    "employee": 3,
    "absence_types" : [
        {
            "id": 602
        }
    ]
}

but when i get all contracts, the i created have is "absences_type" field equal to -> []

Comment: @ArunGowda Using Postman :)

Comment: Let's clear if my understanding is right: You have 2 tables in DB, and have bi-directional mapping in java. You try to create 2 entities and store it in the DB tables, and when you query for contract with a id, you expect contract entity along with associated `absenceTypes`. Is this correct?

Comment: @ArunGowda Exactly ! Because if i create my absenceType in the same time of my contract there is no sense in my situation. 

I want to be able to set already created absenceType, when i create my Contract.

Comment: Can you share the part where you create DB entities and save them to DB?

Comment: @ArunGowda I post a new command to answer you :)

Comment: Any idea ? Still not working :/